# Type synonym for Haskell giving type errors

Tags: haskell, types, ghci

I am attempting to create a type synonym that looks something like this:

```
data Result = Either String [Token]
```

I'm having difficulty because while this code compiles, when I attempt to create a Result with a [Token], haskell complains

```
    Not in scope: data constructor `Result'
```

How can I define a type synonym with a constructor that works?!

Comment: That is not a type synonym, and has nothing to do with type `Either a b` defined in the standard library (Prelude).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How are you trying to create a `Result`??
The correct way is:

If you declare it as a `data`:

```
data Result = Result (Either String [Token])

f :: Result
f = (Result (Left "test"))
```

Or,  if you declare as a `type`:

```
type Result = Either String [Token]

f :: Result
f = Left "test"
```

Comment: Im creating using a statement like f = Result (Right tokens) where tokens is a [Token]

Comment: brilliant. my problem was that I was putting "Result" when I didn't need to. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

With

```
type Result = Either String Token
```

the data constructors are

```
Left :: String -> Result
Right :: [Token] -> Result
```

because

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b
```

With

```
data Result = Either String [Token]
```

you declare `Result` to have one two-argument constructor, `Either` with type

```
Either :: String -> [Token] -> Result
```

which is a) probably not what you want and b) confusing, because `Either` is a well-known type constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use *type* and not *data*

```
type Result = Either String [Token]
```

Comment: True.
Just to complete your answer, when you define a new **data** type you also need to specify a constructor.
Using `data` your declaration would be `data Result = Result (Either String [Token])`